# CakePHP: Ajax post request throws 403 error (permissions all granted)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, http-status-code-403

Ajax request in Cakephp project throws 403 error, all permissions are granted for the project directory in localhost (XAMPP)

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden) /project/users/saveOrder:1

```
var request = function() {
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function() {
                    messageBox.text('Updating the sort order in the database.');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    messageBox.text('Database has been updated.');
                },
            data: 'sort_order=' + sortInput[0].value + '&ajax=' + submit[0].checked + '&do_submit=1&byajax=1', //need [0]?
            type: 'post',
            url: '/project/users/saveOrder',

        });
        };
```

**CODE**
**UsersController:**

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('saveOrder');
    }

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Departments', 'Appointments', 'Roles', 'LeaveRequests', 'TasksTo', 'TasksFrom', 'TasksBy']
        ]); 
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }

    public function change(){
    }
    public function saveOrder() {
        $this->layout = null; 
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {

            $ids = explode(",", $this->request->data['priority']); 
            //print_r($ids); die;
            /* run the update query for each id */
            foreach ($ids as $index => $id) {
                if (isset($id) && !empty($id)) {
                    $query = 'UPDATE tasks SET priority = ' . ($index + 1) . ' WHERE id = ' . $id;
                    //$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error() . ': ' . $query);
                    $data['id'] = $id;
                    $data['priority'] = $index + 1;
                    $this->Task->id = $data['id'];
                    if($this->Task->saveField('priority', $data['priority'])) {
                         echo $query.'<br/>';
                    }else {
                          die('Error, insert query failed');
                    } 
                }
            }
            die;
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue because you haven't allow the function you are using in ajax `url`

Allow that function in your `beforeFilter()` in your controller and then pass function name inside

`$this->Auth->allow()`

Example

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('saveOrder');
 }
```

For more idea on `$this->Auth->allow()`

```
$this->Auth->allow(); //Allow all action define in your controller

$this->Auth->allow('editUser'); //Allow only editUser 

$this->Auth->allow(['editUser', 'AddUser']); //Allow only editUser and AddUser
```

For cakephp 3

1. Put this in top of your controller `use Cake\Event\Event;`
2. Now add this to filter function

   public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
   {

   ```
   parent::beforeFilter($event);
   $this->Auth->allow('saveOrder');
   ```

   }

Comment: tried that but got this error :
>Too few arguments to function Cake\Controller\Controller::beforeFilter(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\src\Controller\UsersController.php on line 16 and exactly 1 expected
ArgumentCountError

Comment: Which version of cakephp you are using?

Comment: I updated op with controller code, I use latest cakephp 3.6.14

Comment: Now I get this error: Call to a member function allow() on boolean

Comment: Probably because I haven't implement login functionality yet?

Comment: Yes might be. Please make that .Above code will definitely work.

Comment: Ι implemented the login functionality but I still get the 403 error....