# CakePHP: Table reordering

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, html-table

I want to implement drag and drop reordering functionality with auto save on a cakephp table.

I am trying to implement this [example](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-dynamic-drag-and-drop-table-rows-using-jquery-ajaxexample.html)  in my CakePHP project without the use of SQL commands.

I want to update the `priority` fields of the table rows.

So in **view.ctp**:

```
  <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Defination</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody class="row_position">
            <?php


            foreach ($user->tasks_to as $task) {


            ?>
                <tr  id="<?php echo $task['id'] ?>">
                    <td><?php echo $task['id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $task['name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $task['description'] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( ".row_position" ).sortable({
    delay: 150,
    stop: function() {
        var selectedData = new Array();
        $('.row_position>tr').each(function() {
            selectedData.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        updateOrder(selectedData);
    }
});


function updateOrder(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"updateTasksOrder",
        type:'post',
        data:{position:data},
        success:function(){
            alert('your change successfully saved');
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

and in the controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow();

}

public function updateTasksOrder()
{
    $this->autoRender = false; 
    $position = $_POST['position'];

    $i=1;
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

    foreach($position as $k=>$v){ 
        $connection->update('tasks', ['priority' => $i], ['id' => $v]);

        $i++;
    }
}
```

But its not working, it's not updating `priority` field. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP: Ajax post request throws 403 error (permissions all granted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54005621/cakephp-ajax-post-request-throws-403-error-permissions-all-granted)

Comment: @GregSchmidt I updated the post in order to describe a different problem I am facing.